# How to check length of response which is not array of objects

Tags: javascript

Hi I am wondering how I can check a length of a response which is not an array of objects?
Can't really shot an example because I don't know how exactly it works in backed I mean I'm looping through an object in a game (which is a battle) and it prints all enemies. But i am getting response with separated objects, not an array of objects.
So my response looks like:

```
{name: "Mike", lvl: 169, team: 1, …}
{name: "Mike2", lvl: 120, team: 1, …}
```

But not an array of these objects.
So I don't really know how I can check what length it is, if it's not an array of objects...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Please show how is the reponse exactly? Is it an object of object or just separated objects?

Comment: Push incoming object in an array and then check for its length

Comment: @Community this is not duplicate at all of what you have mentioned.

Comment: hahah can't blame me. your answer is even found in that thread

Answer (score 0):

```
let json1 = {name: "Mike", lvl: 169, team: 1};
let json2 = {name: "Mike2", lvl: 120, team: 1};
console.log (Object.keys(json1).length);
console.log (Object.keys(json2).length);
```

Answer: 3

Comment: Im looking for a length of all these objects i got in an response, in this case 2... :/

Comment: I am not getting, what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

You can check the number of `keys` your object has:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'cool stuff',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

const count = Object.keys(obj).length

console.log(count);
```

The function has full support and you can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Cheers!

Comment: As i mention i am getting response as a separated objects. And i want to check how much of them i got. Not a length of an object.

Comment: Ohh, I got it. Then you're probably getting them as a 'newline' separated string, am I right?

Comment: Yes, every object is printed in a new line. I've tried to push it to an array. which is outside the loop, and the print the array inside a loop. But it prints this array 1 by 1. Similar to what im getting as a response but now its an array with 1 object inside instead of 1 whole array.

Comment: @Suttero what's wrong with the loop? does it not behave like this? https://codepen.io/hibijvs/pen/pZVoMp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your wanting to split on lines,..

```js
var a = `{name: "Mike", lvl: 169, team: 1, …}
{name: "Mike2", lvl: 120, team: 1, …}`;

console.log("count = " + a.split(/\r?\n/g).length);

//if each line was valid JSON, could even go one better
//and make into an array

var b = `{"name": "Mike", "lvl": 169, "team": 1}
{"name": "Mike2", "lvl": 120, "team": 1}`

b = b.split(/\r?\n/g).map(m => JSON.parse(m));

console.log(b);
```